# Как скомпилировать статическую и динамическую библиотеку в си при помощи cmake?

Tags: c, компиляция, cmake, библиотеки, сборка

Я хочу научиться собирать статический и динамический библиотеки при помощи cmake. В качестве примера, у меня есть простейшая библиотека, состоящая из двух хедеров и двух .с файлов.

Первый файл содержит функцию сложения

```
#include "summator.h"

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

Второй содержит функцию умножения

```
#include "multiplier.h"

int multiplication(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

На данном этапе, cmake проекта имеет следующий вид

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled2 C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(inc)
add_executable(untitled2 inc/summator.h src/summator.c inc/multiplier.h src/multiplication.c)
```

Что мне нужно прописать в cmake для того чтоб скомпилировать из этого кода статическую библиотеку, и что нужно прописать чтоб скомпилировать динамическую? Какие команды нужно запустить в директории с проектом, чтоб запустить сборку?

Comment: [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html) и там же [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_executable` делает исполняемый файл, `add_library` -- библиотеку. У `add_library` можно указать `STATIC | SHARED | MODULE` для нужного типа библиотеки.

Это 2 основные команды CMake, стоит почитать https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html